# Edibility of frozen blended chicken and vegetable smoothie

Tags: food-safety, freezing, spoilage

I boil an eclectic mix of vegetables and some chicken breast (I boil the vegetables and chicken breast separately) then blend everything together in a blender (using water from boiling the vegetables plus some more water). I then pour this smoothie into a Tupperware container and put it in the freezer. My questions are:

1. If after X days, I put my Tupperware container with my frozen smoothie inside the microwave and heat it until it's not frozen (but still cold), will my smoothie still be edible? How high can X be (for how many days can I keep my smoothie frozen before it spoils)?
2. If the answer to 1. is 'yes', approximately for how long will my smoothie be edible? i.e. If I defrost my smoothie in the morning (using a microwave) so that it's a cold liquid then put it in the fridge, will my smoothie still be edible 12 hours later?
3. What could compromise the edibility and the nutrients/enzymes content of my smoothie?

Note that I do not care about taste or texture. Also note that I will not be re-freezing anything defrosted.

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure: you freeze it promptly, keep it frozen, and then defrost it rapidly? Do you have any reason to doubt that it would keep as long as other frozen foods? On the face of it I see no reason for it not to keep indefinitely

Comment: @ChrisH On the face of it, I also see no reason for it not to keep indefinitely too. I am just asking for reassurance and I've been told by some people that freezing vegetables blended with chicken breast 'sounds risky'.

Comment: I suspect that the "sounds risky" comes from your phrasing - the title of this question makes it sound risky, because it's not immediately apparent that this cold dish is fully cooked. But if you think of it as freezing chicken (& veg) soup this seems routine